# drcsim 4.0 release date

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When is drcsim 4.0 expected to be released? We are hoping to update to gazebo 3.0 but are waiting for drcsim support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5927/drcsim-4.0-release-date/) by [dkotfis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/610/dkotfis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Release of the next version of DRCSim (3.2.0) will happen on roughly April 16th.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0